# Memory Management using viewDidUnload function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am pretty new to IOS programming and I am working on my first app that I want to submit to app store.

That's why I made a mistake initializing all objects in `viewDidLoad()` function.  I am using `viewDidUnload()` function to free the memory once the user exits from the view controller. Even though, `x-code` memory checking tool shows that the objects has not been deleted (the RAM usage does not decrease).

Does anyone know how to fix that or I will have to rewrite the whole code?

Comment: did you mean that you UN-initialized the code in viewDidUnload()? Because viewDidLoad is where you should initialize most of your needed code.

Comment: Have you used ARC in your project?

Comment: Use dealloc() function to free the memory. If you are using ARC, dont call [super dealloc]. Now check for the memory test.

Answer (score 2):

[DeprecationAppendix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

**viewDidUnload**

Called when the controller’s view is released from memory. (**Deprecated in iOS 6.0.** Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.)

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
```

Discussion
In iOS 5 and earlier, when a low-memory condition occurred and the current view controller’s views were not needed, the system could opt to call this method after the view controller’s view had been released. This method was your chance to perform any final cleanup. If your view controller stored separate references to the view or its subviews, you could use this method to release those references. You could also use this method to remove references to any objects that you created to support the view but that are no longer needed now that the view is gone. You would not use this method to release user data or any other information that cannot be easily recreated.

In iOS 6 and later, clearing references to views and other objects in your view controller is unnecessary.

At the time this method is called, the view property is nil.

**Memory Management**

Memory is a critical resource in iOS, and view controllers provide built-in support for reducing their memory footprint at critical times. The UIViewController class provides some automatic handling of low-memory conditions through its didReceiveMemoryWarning method, which releases unneeded memory.

Prior to iOS 6, when a low-memory warning occurred, the UIViewController class purged its views if it knew it could reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded from the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. On iOS 6, views are never purged and these methods are never called. If your view controller needs to perform specific tasks when memory is low, it should override the didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidUnload` is deprecated function. (Link [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload)) It is hard to use and not called >= iOS 6.

The view controllers are automatically freed when they are not used. But if there is any reference to the view controllers, they will still reside in the memory. You should check all the strong reference to the view controller.

Answer (score -1):

iOS programming has ARC now, so you dont need to worry about memory problem if you use ARC. [ARC tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: ARC is *not* a simple "do all my memory management for me for free" feature. It just eliminates the need for manual retain/release calls which is only a part of memory management story.

Answer (score -1):

`viewDidUnload` was deprecated in iOS 6. It's no longer being called. If you're using ARC, don't worry about memory management, as everything is taken care of for you. If you aren't using ARC, put your stuff in `dealloc`